# Debugging IE on Windows Phone 7?

Tags: debugging, windows-phone-7, ie-mobile

I'm working on a Mac and I'm wondering what options I have for debugging mobile IE on Windows Phone 7.  There don't seem to be any debugging options under settings (or much else, actually).

Comment: There aren't any debug tools on the device.  You'll need to attach a debugger or use the emulator from the SDK.  Probably best thing to ask is not the options but why you have a problem in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "debuggin mobile IE" I suppose you mean debugging a website on Internet Explorer for Windows Phone?

There is no debugging tools on IE for Windows Phone but what you could do is test your site on IE9 for PC since both share the same codebase (you will need a VM if you work on a Mac).